# Detecting quick rise in time series data

Tags: c#, data-analysis, anomaly-detection

I am trying to detect an anomaly in a time series data. I am a beginner in analyzing data, so I have no idea about detecting anomalies.
Here's the image of what it should look like.
 [Image with good values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViZRt.png)
And here's the image with a very sharp rise in values.
[Image with sharp rise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sRPc.png)

I am looking to detect this in real-time (at most 15-20 data points).

Comment: The first image also have sharp rises, quite often. Are you saying that those level shifts are normal, _not anomallies_?

Comment: It is also not so clear how the two different images and data series are related.